# Show products in boxes using angularjs ng repeat and bootstrap classes, but it is showing in wrong way

Tags: css, angularjs, bootstrap-ui

I want to show products in boxes as products are showing on other ecommerce sites.

I am using AngularJS `ng-repeat` and bootstrap classes, but it is showing products in wrong style.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" id="grdDiv">
    <div ng-repeat="category in groupMenuCategories">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="grpMenuItem in category.menuItems">
            {{grpMenuItem.itemName}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Required Output on website:

item1   item2  item3 item4

item5   item6  item7 item8
.
.
.

Current Output:

item1      item4       item6

item2      item5       item7

item3     (no item)    item8

(no item) -        item9

Link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wyAXgfa2U4gCBtQmYSr2?p=info

Comment: you need to use some col classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ and they need to directly follow your row

Comment: i am using col-md and col-lg, please check now from question,if its place is not ok. then tell me, where to put this.

Comment: i did it,but not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="grpMenuItem in category.menuItems"> 
        {{grpMenuItem.itemName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

to get 4 equal-width columns.

If you need each of 4 columns in seperate rows you can try the following

```
<div ng-repeat="grpMenuItem in category.menuItems" class="row" ng-if="$index<category.menuItems.length/4+1">
    <div  ng-repeat="grpMenuItem in category.menuItems" class="col-sm-3" ng-if="$index>=4*$parent.$index && $index <= 4*($parent.$index+1)-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4zs5iW7HmQFTHcskP2m)**

problem in your code was your menuItem is array therefore you have to get the value itemName this way

```
<div ng-repeat="grpMenuItem in groupMenuCategories" class="row" ng-if="$index<groupMenuCategories.length/4+1">
    <div ng-repeat="grpMenuItem in groupMenuCategories" class="col-sm-3" ng-if="$index>=4*$parent.$index && $index <= 4*($parent.$index+1)-1">
        <h4>{{grpMenuItem.menuItems[0].itemName}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1k5MiZpwIFVY1GwpwALk?p=preview)**

Comment: i added some text in second div, but its not showing anything.

Comment: added demo for you

Comment: @FaseehHaris just change data in demo with your item array.

Comment: i added code and some data, please check from link in my question, i edited the question and provided the data in link